# How to increase multi-tasking skills

Tags: skills

I'm working in my third workplace now. On my first workplace my collegues were really surprised by my multi-tasking skills (I was responsible for up to 17 processes, being part of two different toolchains, additionally I worked on planning and documentation), and I've done this kind of work during ±4 years.

Then I went working in another environment where my multi-tasking skills were not needed: I always just worked on one task at a time. I've worked there during 10 years.

Now I'm working in my third workplace and my multi-tasking skills are required again, but as I didn't work like this during 10 years, I have the impression that my multi-tasking skills have reduced heavily.

As those skills are crucial for my success at my current workplace, I'd like to know if there are ways to increase them.

For your understanding: at this moment I'm 44 years old.

Comment: Step 1: log out of stack exchange. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, multi-tasking is often seen as an anti-pattern for productivity. People naturally get into a rhythm or zone when working on something. Time spent context-switching between tasks (re-orienting yourself) is time away from peak performance.

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with not multitasking. Extended periods of multitasking carry the risk of causing brain damage, so don't overdo it.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you get to Carnegie Hall: Practice. (Sorry, OLD joke.)

Seriously, though, you have to practice. Knock the rust off, as it were. Let them know that you're back to multitasking after a single-project job and it will take you a little bit to get back to 100%. I've done the same with coding languages. "I know language X, but it's been years. Give me a few and I can get back in the swing of things, though". Multitasking is something you do anyway, at least outside the work environment, so once you get your hands dirty you should get back in the swing relatively quickly.

Also, I don't think your age matters. You're aware of your abilities and perceptive of whether or not they have changed, so you're certainly "young enough" to be able to revert to muscle-memory task management.

Also, do some online resources for places to play games or do other tasks to increase your cognition. An article [here](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/225865) can help you.

Comment: Maybe he could complement this training by using effectively some tools  which are made for this purpose :)

Comment: Aye, edit came in as you were writing that. I know there are quite a few video games and sites that will help with this (Brain Age and MultiTaskGames.com) and realized I should be smart enough to include them AFTER I hit enter. ;-P